# Android Studio Flutter Analysis Broken UI

Tags: android-studio, flutter

After upgrading my Android Studio to 4.1.1 the Flutter Analaysis tab UI is broken. I have opened a ticket with Google but no response yet. Any idea what can be wrong? Please, check the following screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found mitigation to this problem here
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5042#issuecomment-728261481

This is the part to fix it

> Turn off 'Enable embedding DevTools' in Preferences > Languages &
> Frameworks > Flutter